# The fat Cantor set is the boundary of the union of open intervals deleted at odd-numbered (or even-numbered) steps

Tags: real-analysis

According to an answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25993/sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-boundary, if we construct a 'fat' Cantor set by removing the middle open interval of length $\frac{1}{4}$ from $[0,1]$, then removing the $2$ middle length $\frac{1}{4^2}$ open intervals from the remaining intervals, and so on (so that the end result is a Cantor set with measure $\frac{1}{2}$), then the sets:

$$U = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on odd-numbered steps} \}$$

$$V = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on even-numbered steps} \}$$

have the fat Cantor set as their common boundary. I fail to see this, can anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Cantor set being fat.  Your Cantor set $C$ is the nested intersection $C= \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n$ of sets of the form $$C_n=I_{n,1}\cup\dots\cup I_{n,k_n}\text{,}$$

where $I_{n,j}$ are disjoint closed intervals.

Furthermore, each point in the Cantor set is a nested intersection of some of these intervals.

In the construction of the Cantor set, every one of these closed intervals is eventually punctured many times by intervals from $U$ and $V$, and thus each interval $I_{n,j}$ intersects both $U$ and $V$.

Since each point in $C$ is a nested intersection of smaller and smaller intervals that touch both $U$ and $V$, we get $C\subseteq \bar{U}$, $C\subseteq \bar{V}$.  Since $C\cap U=\emptyset = C\cap V$, we have $C\subseteq \partial U$ and $C\subseteq \partial V$.

On the other hand, since $U$ and $V$ are open and disjoint from each other, we must have $\partial U\subseteq C$ and $\partial V \subseteq C$.

Comment: Does this also work if instead of taking only $U = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on odd-numbered steps} \}$ and $V = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on even-numbered steps} \}$, we take:

$U_1 = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on 1-modulo-5-numbered steps} \}$, $U_2 = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on 2-modulo-5-numbered steps} \}$, $U_3 = \bigcup \{ \text{open intervals removed on 3-modulo-5-numbered steps} \}$, ..., $U_5$? So the Cantor set is the common boundary of $U_1, U_2, U_3, U_4, U_5$.

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan Yes!  In fact you could go further and let $U_i$ Be intervals removed at every stage in $S_i$, where $S_i\subseteq \mathbb N$ are any decomposition of $\mathbb N$ into infinite subsets. In particular, you could have infinitely many $U_i$’s and it still all works!

Comment: Thank you for your help.